# Form within Iframe not submitted in IE11 using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

From below code, the alert function should be executed after the form submit.But it executes at first time, after that it won't.It executes fine in all browsers except IE11.

Code:

```
<iframe id="iframeID">
<form id="profile">
<input type="file" id="UPLOADED_FILE" name="UPLOADED_FILE" value="" >
<input type="submit" name="save_photo" value="Save" onclick="pressUpload();">
</form>
</iframe>

function pressUpload() {
    var iframe_document = document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow.document;
    var form_profile = $(iframe_document).find('#profile');
    var file_input_field = $(form_profile).find('input[name=UPLOADED_FILE]');

    $(file_input_field).bind('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value) {

            $(form_profile).submit();


            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !window.opera) {
                iframe.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (iframe.readyState == "complete") {

                        alert("HI");
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>That is invalid way to write markup.</strike> but you should not use any element between iframe's opening/closing tags like you have done in your case.

Actually that only gets executed when this element is not supported in any browser. [@MDN you can see the example1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="300" height="300">
 <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I dynamicaly create and and iframe and form like this.
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.id = 'iframeID';   
    iframe.width = '0';
    iframe.height = '0';

    $('#iframe-container').append(iframe);

    //must be https//
    iframe.src = '/account/includes/profile_picture-popup_upload.tmpl';

In source file, we have above mentioned iframe forms format.

Comment: But why do you need to put the form in between iframe open/closing tags? If you have dynamically created it then you should add the generated markup, seems that you presumed it.

Comment: To check whether, the form upload picture is completed or not